# Anchor point not working

Tags: location, anchor, onload, pageload

I'm creating an webpage and wish for it to load at an anchor point in the page but cannot get it working.

Ive got

```
body {
    onload=' location.href="#load" ';
}
```

in the css and

```
<a id="load"></a>
```

where I want the page to load

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<a id="load">` try `<a name="load">`

You can also use a meta refresh instead of location.href.  I'm not sure you'll get the functionality you'd want with your current setup.

`<META http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=#load">`